# Adding React.AspNet causes app.UseMvc to become ambiguous

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, reactjs

I created a new project in VS2015 and chose "Web Application" under "ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates"

After adding `React.AspNet` from NuGet, the project won't build, it fails with the following error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or      properties:    'Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.BuilderExtensions.UseMvc(Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.IApp licationBuilder, System.Action<Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.IRouteBuilder>)' and  'Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseMvc(Microsoft.AspNe t.Builder.IApplicationBuilder,  System.Action<Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.IRouteBuilder>)'  WebApplication3.DNX  4.5.1
C:\Users\UserName\Project\Startup.cs    127
```

**Startup.cs** - This is a simplified version of the default from the template

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Is there something wrong with my **Startup.cs** or is this a bug in React.AspNet?